# onChange event not triggered in react when using select jsx attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am trying to trigger the onChange event of with select jsx/html attribute. The event doesn't fire, here is the code:

```
    const [dataType, setDataType] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState('Art');
    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        console.log("is 3D? ", dataType);
        console.log("event.target.value ", event.target.value);
        event.target.value === "3D" ? setDataType(true) : setDataType(false);
    }
```

jsx section:

```
    <div className="form-group col-md-6 pb-10">
        <select value={data} onChange={handleOnChange} id="category">
            <option value="3D">3D</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
            <option value="Collectibles">Collectibles</option>
            <option value="Photography">Photography</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I am using the latest react version and I followed the doc in this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: can you share codesandbox example ?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: [![Edit sleepy-austin-3k676](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-austin-3k676?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: It works well in sandbox, it seems there is something interfering with the code

Comment: something is wrong in your component. put whole code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actively invoke the `handleChange` function and pass the `event` to your `handleChange` function:

```
onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
```

The complete example then looks like:

```js
<div className="form-group col-md-6 pb-10">
  <select value={data} onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)} id="category">
    <option value="3D">3D</option>
    <option value="Art">Art</option>
    <option value="Collectibles">Collectibles</option>
    <option value="Photography">Photography</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here's a working [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ives-ib440?file=/src/components/Dropdown.js)

Comment: it's not necessary.

Comment: Well it is. Just click the Codebox example

Comment: check out this fork https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-albattani-r75bj

Comment: In your example you still have `onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}`

Comment: @shyammakwana.me the reason why you have to pass the event object in this example is because the original question uses the **arrow syntax** and thus sometimes (usually always) causes binding issues (at least as far I have understood this). Since I personally only use the arrow syntax, I ran into this issue multiple times and I could always solve it the way I do it in my answer. Read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I tried it, the onChange event didn't trigger. The function did not run. This is very perplexing. No error message nothing the function just doesn't run.

Comment: @FloRagossnig file wasn't saved, check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-albattani-r75bj?file=/src/components/Dropdown.js